# overloaded question title

Tags: feature-request, title

Look at the related section from this question:

[The next number in sequence](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72522/the-next-number-in-sequence)

That's a lot of very similar titles, and I don't think there can be many left.

This issue needs addressing, one solution is to perhaps add an unique ID to each title?

Comment: I agree, and could also say the same for Riley Riddles.

Answer (score 6):

No, the proper solution is ***not*** to add a unique ID to each puzzle title.  The solution is to **make more-unique puzzles**, with more-unique titles.  If your puzzle is "Find the next number in this sequence #221", you should be asking yourself whether this site really *needs* a 221st number-sequence puzzle.

Part of the reason for enforcing unique titles is to encourage *unique questions* with *descriptive titles*.

We have seen a ton of number-sequence puzzles and "Riley" riddles, and if it's too hard to think of a unique title for another formulaic and repetitive puzzle, take that as an indication that you have a formulaic and repetitive puzzle, and try something different instead.

Comment: or maybe, if the question was unique to the setter, then they wouldn't need a unique ID. but the problem already exists.

Comment: Whether the question is unique to the setter is irrelevant.  We regularly close questions as duplicates that are "unique to the setter", but that doesn't mean they're unique to the *site*.  This site is a *community* of people working *together* to try to make a *quality* repository of puzzle-related questions and answers.  What may or may not be unique or interesting to an individual setter is largely irrelevant; we are looking for what is unique and/or interesting to the *community*.